# LINQ compare datetime.now ddmmyyyy

Tags: c#, linq

I have this LINQ method syntax which I want to compare the date stored in the collection against system date for ddmmyyyy. My current code is below

```
 var selectedCart = entities.Carts.SingleOrDefault(c => c.UsersId == _user.Id 
            && c.DateCreated.Year == DateTime.Now.Year 
            && c.DateCreated.Month == DateTime.Now.Month
            && c.DateCreated.Day == DateTime.Now.Day
            );
```

Is there any other shorter version than this?

Comment: Just compare a dates? Is stored date time UTC or local?

Comment: Yeah, just compare date, ddmmyyyy. When I add `DateCreated`, I use `DateTime.Now`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date?view=netframework-4.8) property of `DateTime`:

```
c.DateCreated.Date == DateTime.Now.Date
```

Or use the [`Today`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.today?view=netframework-4.8) property instead of `DateTime.Now.Date`:

```
c.DateCreated.Date == DateTime.Today
```